# Twitter JS widget code moved to external file

Tags: twitter, widget

I've been using similar code to the following to get list of recent tweets on a website. There is one problem however which I'd like to have solved. I have to put this code exactly in the place where I want the tweets to be rendered and I'd like to move it to a separate file to keep HTML clean. However I can't really find a way to do it.

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'list',
  rpp: 5,
  interval: 6000,
  title: '@palafo',
  subject: 'Linkers',
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ad0000',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#ad0000'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().start();
</script>
```

Source code for the library is available [here](http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your separate JS file:

```
twitterWidget = new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'list',
  rpp: 5,
  interval: 6000,
  title: '@palafo',
  subject: 'Linkers',
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ad0000',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#ad0000'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}));
```

and then, at the point in your document where you're ready to load the widget, put

```
<script type="text/javascript>
twitterWidget.render().start();
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but I will still need to have inline JS code? I was hoping for an answer that can deal with that.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue, and I can't get @simon solution to work.  It just won't render at all unless I use inline javascript. :(

Comment: Same here, you can't do strict CSP with ANY inlined script

Answer (score 0):

Simon is right however has forgotten to include the src. When your ready to load the document, type -

```
<script type="text/javascript src="path/to/.js/file">
twitterWidget.render().start();
</script>
```